# Implementing Runnable Abstract Class--Multi Threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to call two constructors with different parameters, which in turn run their individual thread but the issue is it only allows one `run()` method, is there anyway i can run two `run()` method in one class?? or any other solution to such situation?

```
class Threading implements Runnable {

    Thread t;
    Thread t1;
    String name;

    Threading(String s) {
        name = s;
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("Constructor 1: " + t);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Constructor 1: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Constructor1 exiting");
    }

    Threading(int a, int b) {
        t1 = new Thread(this, "java2 Thread");
        System.out.println("Constructor 2: " + t1);
        t1.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i++) {
                System.out.println("Constructor 2: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Constructor2 exiting");
    }
}
```

MultipleThread

```
class MultipleThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Threading("java thread"); // Constructor 1
        new Threading(1, 2); // Constructor 2

        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("Print: " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Exit Main");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have two classes?  Why are you trying to use the same class for this?

Comment: Formatting could be improved...

Comment: An alternative would be to use anonymous inner runnables in the constructor. Threading(String){new Runnable() { run(){//your logic}}}

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes I can do that but I just had a thought to try this way. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to implement your `Runnable` with the same `Threading` class. You can implement them anonymously within each constructor:

```
Threading(String s) {
    name=s;
    t=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // ...
        }
    , name);
    System.out.println("Constructor 1: "+t);
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a third class called `MyThread` which implement the `Runnable` interface and have a constructor with an argument, to save which constructor has created it:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{
    private String calledFrom;
    public MyThread(String calledFrom){
        this.calledFrom = calledFrom;
    }
    public void run(){
        try {
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i++) {
                System.out.println(calledFrom + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println(calledFrom+" exiting");            
    }
}
```

Then change your `Threading` class in a way not to implement Runnable interface. Now in your both constructors, you can have different instances of `MyThread` class with different arguments: **"Constructor 1"** and **"Constructor 2"**:

```
class Threading{
    ...
    Threading(String s) {
         name = s;
         //t = new Thread(this, name);
         MyThread mt = new MyThread("Constructor 1");
         System.out.println("Constructor 1: " + t);
         //t.start();
         mt.start();
    }

    Threading(int a, int b) {
         //t1 = new Thread(this, "java2 Thread");
         MyThread mt = new MyThread("Constructor 2");
         System.out.println("Constructor 2: " + t1);
         //t1.start();
         mt.start();
    }
}
```

Passing the **"Constructor 2"** or **"Constructor 1"** to the `MyThread`'s constructor is just an example. You can pass some real and useful arguments to `MyThread` which helps you to separate the implementation by the type or the value of the arguments.

For example you can have two logic method in the `MyThread` class: `logicMethodA()` and `logicMethodB()`, and based on the value of the argument(s) of the constructor, decide to call which one in the `run()` method.

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much , but my concern is - even if i send two different parameters from my MyThread mt = new MyThread("Constructor 1"); and MyThread mt = new MyThread("Constructor 2"); it will every time execute the same run() method that is.. the same for loop will execute. what if I pass the arguments and want different code to execute in run() method, say one for (int i = 5; i > 0; i++) { **} and one for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {**}. can I do that??

Comment: That is what I expressed in the final part of my answer. In a very simple way of thinking you can have an `if-else` on the value of `calledFrom` variable in your `run()` method which switch between calling `logicMethodA()` or `logicMethodB()`. And you logic of loops must be separated in these two `logic...` methods.